# AJAX request with forked callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the problem that I want different callback routes for the same AJAX request because sometime it's necessary to use the same function (i.e. getting information about product ID or something similar).

What works is something like this:

```
function1() {
   $.ajax({
     url: "test.html",
     context: document.body
   }).done(function() {
     route1function();
   });
}
function2() {
   $.ajax({
     url: "test.html", // do the same crap here...
     context: document.body
   }).done(function() {
     route2function();
   });
}
function3() {
   $.ajax({
     url: "test.html", // and here again *yawn*
     context: document.body
   }).done(function() {
     route3function();
   });
}
```

Copy & Paste coding is evil, so my idea was to do something like:

```
doMyAmazingStuff(iRoute) {
   $.ajax({
     url: "test.html",
     context: document.body
   }).done(function() {
     switch(iRoute) {
        case 1:
           route1function(data);
           break;
        case 2:
           route2function(data);
           break;
           // and so on...
     }
   });
}
```

Unfortunately, iRoute will NOT be passed to the .done function and is undefined. Any alternatives how to survive such variables? Copy / paste / paste / paste ... like in the first example is no option (and bad style as well). And making them global scoped  (setting a shadow variable without declaring it with var) isn't a that good solution, I think.

Comment: "iRoute will NOT be passed to the .done function and is undefined": are you sure about this statement, because I don't think it's correct. Have you tested it to make sure?

Comment: if I add an console.log(iRoute), I will get undefined.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, i'm afraid. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

First, your statement "iRoute will NOT be passed to the .done function and is undefined" is incorrect. If you pass in `iRoute` to your function it will not be undefined. See [this demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/yqtyvpvn/2/). I'm passing in `1` as an argument to the function and the alert within the `done` function is alerting that number.

There might be a tidier way of writing that code, but it's pretty much the same code - it just means using the AJAX promise interface to return the data from a separate function instead.

```
function getData() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body
  });
}

function doMyAmazingStuff(iRoute) {
  getData.done(function (data) {
    switch(iRoute) {
      case 1:
        route1function(data);
        break;
      case 2:
         route2function(data);
         break;
    }
  });
}

doMyAmazingStuff(1);
```

Comment: okay, found the mistake. Three different entry points, one with missing value. You're right. Thanks :-)